# <C-z> on gvim (windows) hides the window instead of decrementing the number on cursor

Tags: gvim

`<C-a>` works ok for me, number is incremented. But `<C-z>` does not decrement. Instead gvim window is minimized to be background.

How can I disable that `<C-z>` behaviour and have it increment numbers?

I am using Gvim 7.4 on windows 7 64its and *not* using mswin.vim. I just source a copy of it with most stuff disabled, only minimal mappings. `<C-z>` does not exist in my custom mswin.vim.

Comment: damn I did not check the doc, I was sure it was C-z not sure why...

Comment: Well, `<C-z>` does make more sense; a (the first letter) to increase, and z (the last letter) to decrease ... But `<C-z>` can't be used because it's already used to suspends programs in terminals. I suspect the x was chosen because it's next to the z (on qwerty layouts anyway).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decrement is `<C-x>`, not `<C-z>`.

From [`:help CTRL-Z`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#v_CTRL-Z):

```
CTRL-Z                  Suspend Vim, like ":stop".
                        Works in Normal and in Visual mode.  In Insert and
                        Command-line mode, the CTRL-Z is inserted as a normal
                        character.  In Visual mode Vim goes back to Normal
                        mode.
                        Note: if CTRL-Z undoes a change see mswin.vim.
```

So this works as expected ;-)

If you want to make `<C-z>` behave as `<C-x>`, you can use:

```
:nnoremap <C-z> <C-x>
```